# Putting data back onto a Readable stream

Tags: node.js, stream

**TL;DR** How can I read some data from a stream and then put it back allowing other consumers to get the same `data` event?

Here's a readable stream that streams 1...Infinity:

```
var Readable = require('stream').Readable;

var readable = new Readable();

var c = 0;

readable._read = function () {

    var self = this;

    setTimeout(function () {
        self.push((++c).toString());
    }, 500);
};
```

I want to read the first `data` event, look at the data and then "reset" the stream to its original state and allow other another `data` listener to consume the first event as if it never happened. I thought `unshift()` would be the correct method as it says in the docs:

> readable.unshift(chunk)#
>
> chunk Buffer | String Chunk of data to unshift onto the read queue
>   This is useful in certain cases where a stream is being consumed by a
>   parser, which needs to "un-consume" some data that it has
>   optimistically pulled out of the source, so that the stream can be
>   passed on to some other party.

That sounds perfect for my needs but it doesn't work how I expect:

```
...

readable.once('data', function (d) {

    console.log(d.toString());              // Outputs 1

    readable.unshift(d);                    // Put the 1 back on the stream

    readable.on('data', function (d) {
        console.log(d.toString());          // Heh?! Outputs 2, how about 1?
    });

});
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

So I figured out the answer:

When you call `stream.unshift()` if will emit the data event immediately if the stream is in flowing mode. So by the time I add the listener in my example, the ship has already sailed.

```
readable.unshift(d);                  // emits 'data' event

readable.on('data', function (d) {    // missed `data` event
    console.log(d.toString());
});
```

There's a couple of ways to make it work how I expected:

1) Add the new listener before unshifting:

```
readable.once('data', function (d) {

    console.log(d.toString());              // Outputs 1

    readable.on('data', function (d) {
        console.log(d.toString());          // Outputs 1,1,2,3...
    });

    readable.unshift(d);                    // Put the 1 back on the stream

});
```

2) Pause and resume the stream:

```
readable.once('data', function (d) {

    console.log(d.toString());              // Outputs 1
    readable.pause();                       // Stops the stream from flowing
    readable.unshift(d);                    // Put the 1 back on the stream

    readable.on('data', function (d) {
        console.log(d.toString());          // Outputs 1,1,2,3...
    });

    readable.resume();                      // Start the stream flowing again

});
```

Comment: NB it would seem that as of node 0.12 (tested 0.12.0 and 0.12.4), method (1) doesn't work. Method (2) still does... (using a socket stream -- see https://github.com/brianc/node-pg-copy-streams/pull/28 ). I don't know if this is a bug introduced into "unshift" or a feature -- either way its not documented.

Comment: Note in the second method, there is no need to explicitly call resume. Once you attach a `data` listener, the stream will resume again if it was paused. See https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_two_modes